# Adding a row to a resultset if it does not exist using Oracle Model Clause

Tags: oracle

Given the table

```
D           V
--------------
2019-03-02, 13
2019-10-28, 12
2019-11-22, 34
2020-01-18, 21
2020-04-11, 39
```

I want to add a record with date 2019-12-31 replicating the last one partitioning by year

```
2019-03-02, 13
2019-10-28, 12
2019-11-22, 34
2019-12-31, 34 <<
2020-01-18, 21
2020-04-11, 39
2020-12-31, 39 <<
```

How can this be made using the Model Clause? I cannot even figure out where to start.

Comment: Start with an explanation to us: Why does it have to be done "using the Model Clause", as opposed to "by any means that are available"? Tell us about the restrictions you are facing, which require you to use the Model Clause.

Comment: Well, it's just for educational purpose: I'm exploring what the model clause can and cannot do. The scenario I'm covering here is the possibility of filling gaps in data ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with MODEL:

```
with data(dat, val) as (
    select to_date('2019-03-02', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 13 from dual union all
    select to_date('2019-10-28', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 12 from dual union all
    select to_date('2019-11-22', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 34 from dual union all
    select to_date('2020-01-18', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 21 from dual union all
    select to_date('2020-04-11', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 39 from dual -- union all
),
endofyear(dat, val) as (
    select to_date(y || '-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), null
    from (
        select distinct extract(year from dat) as y from data
    )
)
select dat, val from (
    select row_number() over(order by dat) as rn, d.* from (
        select * from endofyear e
        where not exists(select 1 from data d where e.dat = d.dat)
        union all
        select * from data
    ) d
) 
model
    dimension by( rn )
    measures( dat, val )
    rules (
        dat[ANY] = dat[cv()],
        val[ANY] = nvl(val[cv()], val[cv()-1])
    )
order by dat
;


02/03/2019 00:00:00 13
28/10/2019 00:00:00 12
22/11/2019 00:00:00 34
31/12/2019 00:00:00 34
18/01/2020 00:00:00 21
11/04/2020 00:00:00 39
31/12/2020 00:00:00 39
```

Comment: Great solution! By any chance, have you ever found some good tutorials about the MODEL clause, a part from the official documentation?

Comment: http://www.sqlsnippets.com/en/topic-11686.html

Answer (score 1):

After reading through examples of the model clause and looking at the syntax and trying to work out how to insert rows into a model I reached the conclusion that it was not an easy task (possibly impossible) to solve your question using a `MODEL` clause.

---

However, if you want to use an appropriate method to the problem (as opposed to trying to use a `MODEL` clause for something it was not really designed for), you can use a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

```sql
WITH bounds (d, v, next_d) AS (
  SELECT d,
         v,
         LEAD(d, 1, SYSDATE) OVER ( ORDER BY d )
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(d + INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'YY'), 12) - INTERVAL '1' DAY,
         v,
         next_d
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(d + INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'YY'), 12) - INTERVAL '1' DAY
           < next_d
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY d SET d_order
SELECT d, v
FROM   bounds;
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (D, V) AS
SELECT DATE '2019-03-02', 13 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2019-10-28', 12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2019-11-22', 34 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-01-18', 21 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2020-04-11', 39 FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | D | V |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2019-03-02 00:00:00 | 13 |
> | 2019-10-28 00:00:00 | 12 |
> | 2019-11-22 00:00:00 | 34 |
> | 2019-12-31 00:00:00 | 34 |
> | 2020-01-18 00:00:00 | 21 |
> | 2020-04-11 00:00:00 | 39 |
> | 2020-12-31 00:00:00 | 39 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c2eac1cf8fb7bdca7a4fbb3b5cefbd4f)*

Comment: The OP did clarify that it's for educational purposes; to understand what `model` can and can't do, not to solve this particular problem.

Comment: @MatBailie See the first sentence, I've researched through quite a few examples of model clauses and looked at the schema and could not find a solution; so the answer to the OP's question is that it appears to be very hard (if not impossible) to do using the `MODEL` clause. Then there is an alternate solution using a method appropriate to the problem (which is in addition to answering their question).